# Restoring the value of activity member variable not working

Tags: android, android-activity, state

This is my scenario. I have an activity that is a directory browser. When the user taps on a file in the list of the activity, it will start another activity that will display the file contents.

The second activity has the default back button in the action bar. When I tap on this, I want the first activity to reappear and show the same directory that was open before.

How do I properly store the location and how do I restore it when the first activity becomes active again?

I tried the code below, but the savedInstanceState object in the OnCreate() method is always null and the else branch will be executed! What is the reason for this?

```
private String rootFolder = "/";
private String currentDirectory = rootFolder;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString(getString(R.string.state_current_directory), currentDirectory);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_picker);
    pathDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String lastDirectory = savedInstanceState.getString(getString(R.string.state_current_directory));
        getDirectory(lastDirectory);
    }
    else {
        // THIS BRANCH WILL ALWAYS BE EXECUTED?!?
        getDirectory(currentDirectory);
    }
}
```

Comment: saved instance state are used when your previous activity are recreated or destroy by android used startactivityforresultor used shared preference for it

Comment: I want the previous activity to be recreated and show the directory contents of the directory that was visible when the user tapped on a file entry. So I believe that the instance state is what I need. Or does android create new instances of the same activity every time you click the back button of an action bar. That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: did your onsaveInstanceStateCalled? please put log on it .

Comment: Yes, it is always called. The problem is that the OnCreate() method receives a Bundle object that is always null nevertheless.

Comment: I tried now using OnPause() and OnResume() and shared preferences. OnPause() is called, but when OnResume() is called the stored value is not in the preferences object. Crazy!

Comment: i don't know it will solve your issue or not but can you put savedInstanceState.putString(getString(R.... before super constructor means 
savedInstanceState.putString(getString(R.... 
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

Comment: It is working now using shared preferences. I made a stupid mistake in the code. But this also restores the directory if the application is killed and started later again. How do I avoid that? In that case it should start browsing the root directory again.